# consulta Eloquent con With

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy haciendo una consulta de esta manera.

Las relaciones son

- Usuarios  usuario-places  interesplaces
- publicaciones pub-places interesplaces

```html
$publicaciones = Publicacion::with(['archivos','places' => function($query) use ($listaLugares){
            return $query->wherein('interesplaces.id',$listaLugares);

        }])
        ->whereHas('archivos')
     ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->where('user_id','<>',auth()->user()->id)
  ->paginate(10);
```

Publicaciones tiene lugares - 
entonces, por ejemplo, (publicaciones se comparte en 5 lugares) aparece la lista de places.

Y un usuario igualmente tiene lugares de interés.

Entonces cuando un usuario quiere ver la lista de las publicaciones, estoy intentando mostrar solamente aquellas publicaciones de los lugares que el usuario tiene en favoritos.

Sin embargo, si un usuario no tiene ningún lugar de interés, de todas formas se muestra.

Formas raras que está trabajando

(En esta prueba, un usuario no tiene ningún lugar favorito agregado) pero se muestra la publicación, de esta forma:

```html
data: [
{
    id: 4,
    titulo: "softeeee",
    slug: "sof",
    descripcion: "",
    status: "publico",

  user_id: 1,
  categoria_id: 1,
  created_at: "2019-08-12 21:23:48",
  updated_at: "2019-08-13 01:55:02",
  places: [ ]
}
],
```

places está vacío, pero (eso es incorrecto) se supone que la publicación tiene 5 lugares en donde se puede compartir esa publicación.

Pero entonces si un usuario agrega un lugar favorito, retorno nuevamente el JSON de la publicación y entonces en donde dice places se muestra la que el usuario agregó.

No entiendo porqué hace eso.

**En resumen:**
*Necesito mostrar únicamente las publicaciones que un usuario tenga agregado en su lista de lugares favoritos, cada publicación tiene lugares en donde se puede compartir.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preguntando a un amigo externo solo tenía que hacer esto.

```
   whereHas('places', function ($q) {})->with('user', 'places');
```